# Update transition drawable with new images during program execution?

Tags: android, drawable

In the application I'm making, I'd like to have a background in the main menu that crossfades between different images. The application also allows for the user to take photos. I want to set up the application so that the photos the user takes are also used in the crossfading background.

The [Transition Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html) seems to be the best match for crossfading the background. However, updating the images that the drawable displays without changing the code to add in references to new resources doesn't seem to be possible. Can I update the transition drawable with new images without having to code in the references? If not, is there an alternative way of making this work?

Comment: what do you mean by "having to code in the references"?

Comment: @mibollma Writing XML code into the transition drawable XML file that says "okay, now also have this transition to this jpeg image in the drawable folder".

Answer (score 1):

Use `td.setDrawableByLayerId(td.getId(1), drawable)` on your `TransitionDrawable`. `LayerDrawables` support this.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [the source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.java) to see if it makes sense to derive from it maybe.